# Call a local WebService from .NET c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, visual-studio-2010

I want consume WebService data from a webforms .NET c# application. The WS is not mine, it have been developed by a third person, who have send me two files: .wsdl and .xsd. Then i wanted to try the WS, and used “SOAP UI”. I created a SOAP project loading the .wsdl file and with the .xsd at the same local path. SOAP UI create fine the XML structure call, and when I put the parameters at the XML call, I receive the response fine too from the WS.

Good, now I need call the WS from my .NET c# application. I’ve using Visual Studio 2010.

I’ve been added WS to a Project other times. First right click at “References” in the Project structure, click at “Add service reference”, and finally I put the .wsdl local path. If the .xsd is in the same directory, Visual find the WS with the web methods and I can add the reference correctly. At this point, I have the reference at the “Service references” directory in the project structure, so seems all its OK.

The problem comes when I try to call the WS methods from any application page, seems as the reference is void, and the namespace associated to the WS not exist.

In a aspx.cs file I agree de ‘using’ with the references added, and when I try to call ‘ServiceReference1.”, visual not suggest any, because the namespace is void.

Some idea or help please? If is necessary I could show the .wsdl content.

Thanks and regards

Comment: Please try to improve your question so that it clearly states what it is that you're trying to solve. As it is written it's very hard to understand.

Comment: I have improved the question. Hope it could be understanded now

Comment: It is better, but what would make this answerable is some of the code that you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar on a previous project. I was calling the WCF service hosted in windows service from a web page. Only way you can do this is by calling the service on localhost using javascript but there are some tweaks required for enabling cross domain calls and security of your web service. If you want it to work over reference you need to expose your service over a known address and then import it like that into your project.

Comment: JavaScript is not the only way to call a WCF service from a web page.  You can do it in the code-behind as well.

Comment: @Tim From a web page javascript IS the only way. Codebehind is executed on a server :)

Comment: Semantics :)  OP stated they were using a Web Forms application, so code-behind is a perfectly acceptable way to call a web service, and you avoid cross-domain issues as well.